# Can you map, tap, and/or inject the splat operator?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of arrays of arrays.  I was wondering if you could splat out the middle arrays.

```
# Example Input
x = [[[139, 65], [176, 83]], [[203, 65], [139, 83]], [[139, 75], [176, 93]], [[203, 75], [139, 93]]]
```

Splat the innards to

```
[[139, 65], [176, 83], [203, 65], [139, 83], [139, 75], [176, 93], [203, 75], [139, 93]]
```

Using `map(&:*)` only injects the multiplication method and raises an error.  Is there a method splat with an alternative name we might use instead?

If not it'd be fairly easy to write the method to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discover [`Array#flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
x = [[[139, 65], [176, 83]], [[203, 65], [139, 83]], [[139, 75], [176, 93]], [[203, 75], [139, 93]]]
x.flatten(1) # => [[139, 65], [176, 83], [203, 65], [139, 83], [139, 75], [176, 93], [203, 75], [139, 93]]
```

Comment: Ah.  I didn't know you could hand flatten a value.  This works.  Thank you!

Comment: You could also use `x.inject(&:+)`: `[1] + [2] # => [1,2]`

Comment: @DaveMongoose: yep, or that one.

Comment: @DaveMongoose: yes, but that's `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @tokland it's difficult to come up with `Big O` values in this situations, because you need to put into consideration what ruby is doing in background with this method calls, I think a benchmark would be the easiest way to determine which is faster/slower

Comment: @bjhaid: I don't think Ruby cannot work magic here, with big inputs a O(n^2) algorithm will perform very poorly. `xss = 10000.times.map { (1..10).to_a.product((10..20).to_a) }

Benchmark.bm(10) do |b|
  b.report("flatten") { xss.flatten(1) }
  b.report("reduce") { xss.reduce(:+) }
end` flatten      0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.175329)
reduce     224.390000   0.080000 224.470000 (225.922035)